# ASP.NET Core Identity - LoginPartial broken after scaffolding identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-identity

I created a new Project from the VS 2017 template (web application with individual user accounts).

This adds the ASP.NET Core Identity as default UI (using the UI from a nuget).

```
  services
    .AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

With this nuget everything works as expected. Especially the loginPartial which shows the username once a user has logged in and shows the Login Button right after clicking logout.

Once I scaffold the layout and apply the changes (according to [the guide in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)) the Logout does not remove the name and show the login button anymore (right after the click on logout). The change only happens when I click on a link to another page.

Of course I changed the configuration (according to the guide):

```
 services
   .AddIdentity<Data.Entities.ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or what the difference is between the DefaultUI and the scaffolded classes?

Comment: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design version 2.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/937) that describes the exact problem you're running in to. The Razor Class Library (RCL) implementation you were using indirectly before scaffolding has an `OnPost` implementation in `Logout.cshtml.cs` that looks like [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/Account/Logout.cshtml.cs#L47):

```
public override async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string returnUrl = null)
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
    if (returnUrl != null)
    {
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        // This needs to be a redirect so that the browser performs a new
        // request and the identity for the user gets updated.
        return RedirectToPage();
    }
}
```

As the inline comment explains, it's a `RedirectToPage` that's needed to ensure the identity gets reloaded after being cleared. If you look at your scaffolded version of this method, you'll find that it has the following in the `else` branch:

```
return Page();
```

That's the problem. There's no redirect, so there's no reloading of the identity. You can resolve the problem by switching that to use `RedirectToPage`, as shown in the RCL implementation I called out above.